# What factors of the hardware make one WiFi card better than the other?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I two computers:

- desktop with [Asus WiFi PCI card: PCI-e N10](https://www.asus.com/Networking/PCEN10/).
- MacBook Pro with [AirPort Extreme card](https://www.apple.com/ie-edu/shop/product/M8881J/A/airport-extreme-card) (firmware version: Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.95.175.1a6))

Both connected to the Internet through a dual band WiFi router.

MacBook Pro downloads files from the Internet faster than the desktop if both computers are located in the same place (so it's not about WiFi dea zones).

What factors of the hardware make one WiFi card faster than the other?

Comment: Besides the hardware recommendation question, which is off topic: Too many factors, from lots of hardware details to firmware details. There's no simple guide.

Comment: @dirkt So how should I ask this question? Should I ask for factors to make informative decision? Can you help me reword it?

Comment: It may have more to do with the way the OS handles networking generally and WiFi specifically. If you can measure the WiFi speed to the router and these differ, then it may be down to aerial placement: perhaps an external aerial on the desktop will help. Once the WiFi rates are comparable, then you need to look at OS differences - it could be a driver, which may be improved by an update. You could make a test by running an alternative OS on the desktop (you don't say which OS) from a Linux live CD (if Windows) or a Windows diagnostic disc (if Linux).

Comment: Related on another SE site: [Why do two smartphones connected to the same WiFi network show different speeds (one displays the link speed as 135 Mbps and other only 72 Mbps)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/177323/209414)

Comment: @dirkt I disagree. This is totally answerable. The high-level list of relevant hardware factors is pretty short. MCSes, Spatial Streams, channel widths, bus speed, high power Tx PAs, high quality Rx LNAs.

Comment: @Spiff: The thing is, even on 802.11g with no spatial streams, same channel width, same bus speed etc., you can get wildly varying results in reception quality and bitrate under difficult circumstances. And "high quality Rx LNAs" isn't something you can read up on the specs of the card. Of course, if both card supports different standards, speed will be different, but I didn't take that as the question.

Comment: @dzieciou MacBook Pro's never took the AirPort Extreme card pictured in your link. Also, BCM43xx isn't much to go on because pretty much ALL of Broadcom's Wi-Fi chips for the last decade have started with 43xx if I recall correctly. Please go to  > About This Mac > System Report… > Hardware and give the "Model Identifier" of your Mac. It will be in the format "MacBookProX,Y", like "MacBookPro13,3". It would also help to know the exact model of your router, so we can look up technical details.

Answer (score 1):

There are a large number of factors -

In a nutshell, its all about "Signal to Noise" ratio - the greater the signal to noise ratio, the greater the throughput.   (relatedly, the greater the spectrum used , the greater the amount of signal)

What this means to you -

One factor is the channel width. Some devices can handle combined channels, others can't.  This can mean a significant increase in speed for the device that can use 2 channels over the device that can use only 1 (assuming the router supports it)

Multiple antennas and radios.  Newer devices have multiple antennas to help work out where a signal is coming from and cancel out noise, to effectively boost the amount of data/range.  Depending on the circuitry in the sender and receiver this may work better or worse.

Antenna design - Bigger antennas generally provide better reach in practice.  Thus if you have an antenna on a cellphone it may be smaller and not able to go as far as a larger laptop antenna.  Similarly the spacing between multiple antennas can make a difference - larger spacing is often better, but the device may not have space for it.

Chipset - some chipset and designs are better at differentiating between the signal and noise then others.  This can make a massive difference.

Firmware - Buggy firmware can slow things down quite a lot and cause unreliablity, by not correctly implementing the standard.

Different frequencies - newer (802.11ac) devices can work on 5 and 2.4 gig bands.  If the older device does not have an 802.11ac chip, they may be using a saturated band in the 2.4 gig range, as opposed to cleaner, more plentiful (but not as far reaching) channels in the 5 gig band.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the main hardware factors affecting performance (including performance at range):

1. **Number of *spatial streams*.** 802.11n and 802.11ac support MIMO, where there are multiple *radio chains* per card (some people conflate this with the number of *antennas* per card). By adding a second, third, or even fourth radio chain, you can transmit 2x, 3x, or 4x the amount of data per second, respectively. Sometimes the number of radio chains and spatial streams is specified as TxR:S, such as "3x3:3", where T is the number *transmit* radio chains supported, R is the number of *receive* radio chains supported, and S is the number of *spatial streams* supported. I've seen 4x4:2 radios before, so there's no guarantee that you'll get as many spatial streams as you have radio chains, which is why it's nice to see the number after the colon.
2. **"Modulation and Coding Schemes" (MCSes).** Basically, every new addendum to 802.11 that adds performance (like 802.11a, b, g, n, and ac), adds newer, more complex ways to manipulate the radio wave transmissions to squeeze in more data per second. Original 802.11-1997 DSSS only had two MCSes, providing the 1 and 2 Mbps data rates. 802.11b added two more, providing the 5.5 and 11 Mbps data rates. MOST of the time if a product says it supports, say, 802.11n or 802.11ac, it will support ALL the MCSes from that 802.11 addendum that apply to the number of spatial streams they support. But that's not always true. 802.11ac added a pair of MCSes that use a modulation called "QAM256". These were MCSes 8 and 9 of 802.11ac. Some cheap 802.11ac gear out there doesn't support QAM256.
3. **Channel width.** Wi-Fi channels can be 20, 40, 80, or even 160MHz wide. By doubling the channel width, you slightly-more-than-double the amount of data you can transmit per second. 802.11n added 40MHz channels, and 802.11ac added 80 and 160MHz channels, but most 802.11ac gear doesn't do 160MHz channels yet. 802.11n supported 40MHz-wide channels even in the crowded 2.4GHz band, and some vendors chose not to support that mode because it crowds out other uses of the band, such as Bluetooth. Apple in particular has never supported 40MHz operation in 2.4GHz, because Apple products make a lot of use of Bluetooth.

Your ASUS PCE N10 is the wimpiest thing that can be called 802.11n. The big deal with N is that it supported MIMO, yet that card only has a single radio chain, so it can't do MIMO. 802.11n was also defined for both 2.4GHz and 5GHz operation, but that card only does 2.4GHz. In order to claim to support 150Mbps, it supports 40MHz-wide channels in 2.4GHz, but if you connect it to, say, an Apple AirPort base station that, per Apple policy, doesn't support 40MHz operation in 2.4GHz, your card will only be able to get 72Mbps max, which is hardly better than 802.11a's 54Mbps from 2002.

Apple's MacBook Pros typically have some of the best stock built-in cards of any laptop vendor.

- All MacBook Pros up through 2009 had 2 spatial stream 802.11n (300Mbps operation with 40MHz channels in 5GHz).
- 2010-2012 had 3SS 802.11n (450Mbps operation with 40MHz channels in 5GHz).
- 2013-2015 had 3SS 802.11ac (1300Mbps operation with 80MHz channels in 5GHz).
- I believe I heard that the 2016+ touchbar MBPs may have stepped down to 2x2:2 802.11ac (867 Mbps) to save space.
  All of those also support 2.4GHz operation too, but they limit themselves to 20MHz-wide channels there, which means the numbers aren't as impressive.

There are also several less important hardware factors that can affect how fast a given Wi-Fi card is, including:

- How fast is the bus it connects to? If you have a Wi-Fi dongle that supports 867Mbps 802.11ac signaling, but it only does USB 2.0, it's going to be limited to something less than 480Mbps just like all other USB 2.0 stuff.
- How good are its transmit and receive amplifiers? High-power PAs (Power Amplifiers = transmit amplifiers) can transmit strong signals that can reach APs that are farther away. High quality LNAs (Low-Noise Amplifiers = receiver amplifiers) can do a better job of boosting reception of transmissions from distant APs.
- How efficient are its antennas at focusing power in the directions that matter? When you optimize an antenna to focus power in one direction (as opposed to transmitting radio power equally in all directions like a sphere), that's called "directional gain". You gain power in one direction by losing it in another direction. Antenna gain on a phone or laptop can be tricky, because there's no way to know which direction the nearest AP is, so there's no way to know which direction to focus the power in the antenna design. At least the antenna should be designed to point the power *outside* of the computer, and not into the RF-shielding of the computer. It's a myth that antennas have to be bulky to be good. The kernel of truth at the core of the myth is that it's easier for a mediocre antenna designer to design a good antenna if he's not constrained by size constraints. Good small antennas are possible and even common, they're just costlier to design, and often costlier to produce.
- MIMO gains unrelated to spatial streams. Having more antennas and more radio chains gives you a better chance at having an antenna located in a good place to receive a good signal. Multiple radio chains also allows for "beamforming" where the chains are used to make a "phased array" out of the antennas, which allows the system's directional antenna gain to be steered in different directions.
- Quality issues in hardware/firmware/driver. Not everyone makes high-quality radios, firmware, and drivers. Lousy hardware designs and buggy software can be a deal-breaker.